# ¿Cómo vaciar un arreglo de objetos con alguna función del SDK de JAVA?

Tags: java

Necesito alguna función del SDK de JAVA que me vacíe un arreglo de objetos, una forma que implementé es recorrer con un for el arreglo y poner todos sus valores a NULL, pero si saben de alguna función predefinida que haga este trabajo se lo agradecería a la comunidad y en especial al que me de la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: si pones algo del código que intentas escribir te podemos ayudar mejor

Comment: reinicializa el array con new.

Answer (score 1):

Como no has escrito código, voy a pensar que estás utilizando un `ArrayList<Objeto>`:

```
ArrayList<object> lista = new ArrayList();


 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    lista.add(i);    
}
```

Aquí tenemos la lista llena con números del 1 al 10.

Para vaciarla puedes utilizar el método `clear()`:

```
lista.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes rellenar todos los valores de tu array a nulo con la siguiente función:

```
Arrays.fill(tuArray, null);
```

En realidad hará el mismo comportamiento que cuando lo inicializas con el bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando con una lista de objetos :

`List<TuObjeto>` basta con que llames al metodo `lista.clear();`

Si estas trabajando con un `Array` puedes :

- Igualarlo a `tuArray = null;`
- Dar un nuevo largo `tuArray = TuObjeto[0];`